# What test suite should be for http library?

Tags: php, curl, network-programming, tdd

I want to write open source PHP library for HTTP fetching, based on curl with unit tests. There will be features like, proxy tunneling, several network interfaces (if it available) usage, parallel request execution, etc.

But how should I test all this things? I mean, should I test success get requests, like this:

```
$myVeryGoodLIbraryClass->get('http://google.com')
```

Or create `Apache config file` for local test site? Or how can I test proxy servers? Should I put Squid config file in `tests` directory of my library?
I know all of that stuff matters for people who will want participate in it, so I want make development for other people (and myself :)) more convenient.

Comment: You could host test site and a proxy for yourself and make sure it is available. Or use a site and a proxy that is unlikely beeing down. Like example.org etc.